# How to run macro stored in a file

Tags: vba, vbscript, ms-word

Is it possible to run a macro sub or functions stored in say .bas file?

I want to make a `vbscript` that can open a word document and run a macro function from `.bas` file. I know that this is possible using macro enabled document but what about `.bas` file or `.text` file?

so that from vbscript

```
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(sFile)
'some code here to import the macro form a file
wrdApp.run("macroname")
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Ok. I also thought so but wanted to confirm.

Comment: I confirm that what you describe is *not* possible - and it would be a tremendous security loophole BTW. What Dave suggests is possible, but the setting he mentions is blocked by installation default since this also presents a major security risk. And he neglects to mention that  once the code has been imported you *must* automate the Word application using `Application.Run` to run the macro code.

Comment: Thanks. I don't under why running macro a text source in vbscript by first importing will be security concern. The person, can breach the security be vbscript itself, why he would go to vba for breach of security. I don't have much knowledge about vba but I think vbscript can pretty much do everything that can be breach of security that vba possibly can do.

Comment: I wasn't neglecting to mention it @CindyMeister, the OP's code example shows they are automating the Word instance, document open and then the macro run from vbscript; all that was missing was how to import the module.  The OP already had the wrdApp.Run (Application.Run) statement in place, so I saw no need to specify it..

Comment: Security: If programmatic access is granted to the VBE then any outside (malicious) code can load / create macros and run them in the Office application. When this setting is not enabled, the code must already be in an Office document that the user has trusted and opened. That's why the suggested approach is a security risk: enabling code from outside Word to create *new* code in Word and run it.

Comment: @Dave Sorry, I was totally focussed on the external *.bas file and my brain simply stopped at that point. You are correct. And I'd delete that comment except for the security issue; unfortunately, it can no longer be edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the code you're looking for to import a module (a .bas file) can be achieved with:

```
wrdApp.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import "C:\temp\yourmodule.bas"
```

You will need to ensure that programmatic access to the VB Project object model is enabled.

Comment: Dave, will this work in Excel 365?  Could I then simply ```Call``` any macro Subs that are in that .bas file?

Comment: @Scott I haven't tried it to be honest.  If it works (note that you'd probably need to call the `VBProject` belonging to the associated `workbook` object rather than the `application` level object), then once the `.bas` is imported, yes, you should be able to use functions within that file by calling them from elsewhere.  I think.  Someone may come along and correct me though!